# Why does my control group show no memory usage in cgget and systemd-cgtop, despite containing a process using significant memory?

Tags: memory, cgroups

I'm trying to implement a solution to [this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373312/oom-killer-doesnt-work-properly-leads-to-a-frozen-os) using control groups, which I have never worked with before. As a first step, I thought I would create a control group, add a process to it, and view its memory usage.

I ran the following code:

```
sudo apt install cgroup-tools
sudo cgcreate -g memory:/jupyterHub
sudo cgclassify -g memory:/jupyterHub --sticky 805
```

805 here is the `jupyterhub` process. Ultimately, I want to limit the memory usage of 805 and all of its children, so that the OOM-killer is invoked when the memory usage is too high. When I run

```
sudo ps -o cgroup 805
```

it shows the `jupyterHub` group as expected.

However, when I run

```
sudo cgget -g memory:/jupyterHub
```

it reports 4KB of memory usage, which is definitely wrong and I'm pretty sure corresponds to the process using zero memory.

```
systemd-cgtop
```

gives the same result. How can I create a control group containing `jupyterhub` and its children that will report the correct amount of memory usage?

Also, please tell me if I'm doing something dangerous here (although I'm already planning on creating a duplicate server for testing so that I don't bork up the production one).

Comment: I have a very few knowledge about `cgroups`. And what I've known is that to manage `cgroups` you can use `systemd` (I'd prefer learning to use cgroups by the commands rather than using systemd). Maybe you have to enable/disable some option in your system (maybe kernel parameters in `/etc/default/grub`). Or maybe you are using the wrong cgroups version since there `v1` and `v2`